# Linq query not returning expected number of results

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have two data models:

```
public class SSC {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //other irrelevent properties removed for brevity
    public virtual ICollection<SpecReference> SpecReferences { get; set; }
}

public class SpecReference {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //other irrelevent properties removed for brevity
    public virtual ICollection<SSC> SSCs { get; set; }
}
```

I have defined a many-to-many relationship between the two in my data context as:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SSC>().HasMany(a => a.SpecReferences)
    .WithMany(b => b.SSCs)
    .Map(c => {
        c.MapRightKey("SpecReference_Id");
        c.MapLeftKey("SSC_Id");
        c.ToTable("SpecReferenceSSCs");
    });
```

At one point in my site, I have an advanced search page from which users can search for SSCs by a combination of any field in the SSC or any navigation field attached to the SSC.  Every search is working except when a user specifies a SpecReference.  The query code (abbreviated to show only relevant code) is:

```
var query = _dbContext.SSCs.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted);

if (designSpecificationIds != null && designSpecificationIds.Any()) {
    var designSpecificationIdsHash = new HashSet<int>(designSpecificationIds);
    query = query.Where(x => x.SpecReferences.Any(s => designSpecificationIdsHash.Contains(s.Id)));
}
```

where designSpecificationIds is an array of integers passed from the web form.

When I run the application and step through the search code, the SQL generated from the query is:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[SSCId] AS [SSCId], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[SystemFunction] AS [SystemFunction], 
[Extent1].[Remarks] AS [Remarks], 
[Extent1].[IsSystem] AS [IsSystem], 
[Extent1].[IsGrouping] AS [IsGrouping], 
[Extent1].[IsConfiguration] AS [IsConfiguration], 
[Extent1].[FieldTag] AS [FieldTag], 
[Extent1].[ParentId] AS [ParentId], 
[Extent1].[IPlantParentId] AS [IPlantParentId], 
[Extent1].[BuildingId] AS [BuildingId], 
[Extent1].[IsOperable] AS [IsOperable], 
[Extent1].[IsAvailable] AS [IsAvailable], 
[Extent1].[DutyAreaId] AS [DutyAreaId], 
[Extent1].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted]
FROM [dbo].[SSCs] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[IsDeleted] <> 1) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[SpecReferenceSSCs] AS [Extent2]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[SSC_Id]) AND ([Extent2].[SpecReference_Id] IN (4))
))
```

If I run this SQL against the database, I get the one result that I expect.  However, when I examine the Linq query and attempt to enumerate the results, I get "Enumeration yielded no results."  How is it possible that the SQL generated by a Linq query is returning different results than the query itself?

Edit:
To return the values, I'm using ExpressMapper to convert the Model to a DTO.  The conversion is simply:

```
return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<SSC>, IEnumerable<SSCIndexDto>>(query);
```

The DTO is:

```
public class SSCIndexDto {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //Other properties omitted for brevity
    public List<SpecReferenceIndexDto> SpecReferences { get; set; }
}
```

Again, the mapping appears to be working correctly for all other properties, including navigation properties that are written exactly like SpecReferences.  It's the query itself that's not returning any data.

Comment: you are not executing the query like `query = query.Where(x => x.SpecReferences.Any(s => designSpecificationIdsHash.Contains(s.Id))).ToList();`

Comment: At the end of the search code, I use ExpressMapper to convert the model to a DTO for display on the page.  However, if I put a breakpoint on the line directly after the SpecReferences are added to the search and I do a Quick Watch on the query, it has no results.

Comment: That's weird. Did you try with "_dbContext.SSCs.Include(x=> x.SpecReferences).Where"?

Comment: Yes.  Adding the Include makes the generated SQL more complex, but doesn't change the results either way.

Comment: Can you show the actual query execution line (like `.... ToList()` or `foreach....`)? I know it shouldn't make a difference, since you posted the SQL, but just to be sure :)

Comment: What's the role of this column `[Extent1].[SSCId]`? (Note: not `[Extent2].[SSC_Id]`).

Comment: It's the unique identifier of the object.

Comment: Then what's `Id`? Isn't `[SSCId]` a foreign key? I'm trying to find out if there are other associations that may interfere with the many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't design this table.  There's no foreign key on SSCId.  Even though it's unique, the designer thought it should have an Id field as well, so the relationships are on the Id field.